# HTML Print a Page with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, linux, printing

I have a problem, with html print function. So my plan is the following. I have a page in the /help-center/ folder as index.html. So I want to do the following: As you can see in the picture there is a "Print" link. So when the user clicks on it, it should print the /help-center/pdf/terms.html file.

This is a code:
Print this page

And I want to do that to set the parameters to print the /help-center/terms.html page

The image: https://ibb.co/j59JmcF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i understand this is what you want?

```js
function printPreview(){
  var targetFile= window.open('/path/to/file');
      targetFile.print(); 
}
```

Comment: No, I meant: There is a folder: folder/ and the inde.html contains a button: Print. So the print button should print the folder/print/file.html

Comment: ok i am editing my answer for you, please check again.